# how to get the element selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

The dropdowns on the top right, I need to get the first three characters of the string of the type selected for example if the user selects Pizza Delivery i need the string "piz"

here is the [url](http://posnation.com/pre_config/pre_config_step_3.php?type=Restaurant&count=1)

```
    <div class="select-big select-small right">
<div class="select-holder">
<div class="button">
<div class="icon left"></div>
<p class="text left">Fast Food Pos System</p>
<a href="#" class="trigger right"></a>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s1">Grocery</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s2">Pizza Delivery</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s3">Quick Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s4">Retail</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s5">Salon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icon-s icon-s6">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the Jquery that I am working with

```
    $('.select-big ul li a').click(function () {
$(this).parents('.select-holder').find('.text').text($(this).text());
     // I need the string here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), like this:

```
$('.select-big ul li a').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('.select-holder').find('.text').text($(this).text());
  var type = $(this).text().substring(0, 3).toLowerCase();
  alert(type);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3S3rh/1/)

Comment: Is it possible to add this variable to the string 

  var type = $(this).text().substr(0, 3).toLowerCase();
$("#main_content").load("function.php?type={type}&count=5");

is that the right syntax

Comment: @John - You could just append it, e.g.: `$("#main_content").load("function.php?type=" + type + "&count=5");` or a bit cleaner: `$("#main_content").load("function.php?count=5&type=" + type);`